# Выравнивание flex элементов в резиновой верстке

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Каким образом выравниваются элементы в резиновой верстке с учётом переполнения?
Не могу разобраться с отступами.
Есть код https://codepen.io/nomiy/pen/KKwWORq:

```
<div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  background-color: #eef2f5;
 }

.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.item:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.item:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Всё хорошо когда блоки помещаются на весь экран:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Всё плохо когда экран становится уже:

1. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чего вы ожидали?  Зачем вам такие селекторы .item:nth-child(4n) item:nth-last-child(-n+4) ?  Вы раз уж решили считать кому какие отступы давать, тогда и при адаптации считайте дальше. какое вам поведение вообще нужно?

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае у вас проблема в том что вы жестко задали отсутствие отступа для каждый 4го элемента. И в случае если он не помещается у него все равно не будет отступа.
Могу предложить такой вариант размещения с блока произвольной ширины

```css
.row {
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row-cell {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text Text TextTex</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text TextTextText Text Text Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">TextText TextTex</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text TextTextTextText Text Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Либо вот с жестко заданной шириной

```css
.row {
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row-cell {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 25%;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text Text TextTex</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text TextTextText Text Text Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">TextText TextTex</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text TextTextTextText Text Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell">
    <div class="block">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ну соответственно с помощью медиа запросов вы можете изменить ширину блока до 50% (например), тогда у вас будет отображаться 2 блока в ряд.
Подобная разметка вообще избавит вас от необходимости задавать какие-то отдельные отступы для определенных блоков